# Should an organization admin always be assigned the type admin?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

While reading the [**Fabric CA Operations Guide**](https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/operations_guide.html#) I noticed that the admins of the Org 1 and 2 were not assigned the type of **admin** when registering them in the corresponding CA as shown below:

```
fabric-ca-client register -d --id.name admin-org1 --id.secret org1AdminPW --id.type user -u https://0.0.0.0:7054
fabric-ca-client register -d --id.name admin-org2 --id.secret org2AdminPW --id.type user -u https://0.0.0.0:7055
```

To make things worst I found another entry where the admin of the Org 0 was in fact registered with type admin:

```
fabric-ca-client register -d --id.name admin-org0 --id.secret org0adminpw --id.type admin --id.attrs "hf.Registrar.Roles=client,hf.Registrar.Attributes=*,hf.Revoker=true,hf.GenCRL=true,admin=true:ecert,abac.init=true:ecert" -u https://0.0.0.0:7053
```

Why this distinct behavior for the above registrations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set up NodeOUs in your MSP, you must specify "admin" (or another identifier you specify in your `config.yaml`). This way, `OU` is set suitably in the enrolled certificate so that it is considered an admin.

If you don't set up NodeOUs in your MSP, then only certificates under `admincerts` in the MSP folder are considered admins. It does not matter its type or OU.

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/msp.html#organizational-units

Comment: I was following along the tutorial and they did not mention anything about that, so, I ended up really confused and puzzled. Btw, for this specific case the admin role should be set in an `NodeOU` instead of an `OU`, right?

Comment: When you register an identity with a type, that type is set automatically as OU in the certificate when enrolling. If "admin" type was specified during register and "admin" is specified in your `config.yaml` NodeOU configuration file as the admin identifier (and NodeOUs are enabled), then the user will be an admin. Certificates under `admincerts` folder are always admins whether NodeOUs are enabled or not.

Comment: So, to assign the type admin I have to specify that type in advance under the `NodeOU` section otherwise it will not be granted admin privileges?

Comment: You can assign always the type you want or invent. But in order to be considered an admin, NodeOUs must be enabled in your application channel (as created from the transactions sourced from your `configtx.yaml`, if not updated) and in your peer MSP folder. Otherwise, you must update your application channel configuration and your peers' MSP (this second one is very easy).

Comment: To sum it up, if I want to assign the admin type on registration I have to set it up in advance in the `NodeOU`s but then that type after enrolling the said user will end up in the `OU` section of the generated certificate, right?